# Unable to locate package update-manager-core

Tags: upgrade, apt

Following the guide [I found here](http://code.curiouscatnetwork.com/2012/10/15/upgrading-vps-web-server-from-ubuntu-10-04-to-12-04/) I am trying to upgrade my Ubuntu version from 10.10 to 12.04.
As  `do-release-upgrade` gave the error **command not found** I tried to install `update-manager-core` which results in this error

```
root@myserver:~# apt-get install update-manager-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
E: Unable to locate package update-manager-core
```

Now I'm stuck, as [nobody else on the web](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Unable%20to%20locate%20package%20update-manager-core%22) seems to have that issue

Comment: Try running `apt-get update`, then `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to the experience he got upgrading of Ubuntu is only supported step by step - except with LTS-versions, where you can take the bigger steps LTS -> LTS.

In your case that means you would only be able to upgrade to 11.04 reliably. **But** all these releases are EOL, they are not supported any more. For this reason I suggest you back up the essential parts of your system and install 12.04 LTS.

What should you back up? The debian project has a [very good description](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#data-backup). It boils down to:

> - `/home`
> - `/etc`
> - `/var/lib/dpkg`
> - `/var/lib/apt/extended_states`
> - the output of `dpkg --get-selections "*"` (the quotes are important).
> - If you use `aptitude` to manage packages on your system, you will also want to back up `/var/lib/aptitude/pkgstates`.
> - data for any servers you have running